# Downloading data from online map?

Tags: data, dem, arcgis-online, export

I am trying to download a hillshade map of africa. I found the perfect one, namely this: 
South Africa 5m resolution hillshade
http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=219dc4347a594455bdf239c8eb4b581c

I open the downloaded link with the ArcMap and I see the map but it is not a raster and I can't figure out how to download it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ArcGIS.com resource is:

> A hillshade of the 5m resolution Stellenbosch University Digital
>   Elevation Model (SUDEM) accessible online through free Web Mapping
>   Service made available by the University of Stellenbosch.

It is offered as an OGC Web Map Service (WMS) and does not provide a data download service.